# Write a program that gives me the Day of the Year using a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to write a program that gives me the Day of the Year using a dictionary.

```
import sys
Month = str(sys.argv[1])
Day = int(sys.argv[2])

m = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
Months = {"Jan": 31, "Feb": 28, "Mar": 31, "Apr": 30, "May": 31, "Jun": 30, "Jul": 31, "Aug": 31, "Sep": 30, "Oct": 31, "Nov": 30, "Dec": 31}
a = m.index(Month)
b = m[0:a]
for i in range(len(b)):
c = b[i]
d = Months[c]
e = sum(d) + Day
print(e)
```

When I run it, it gives me:

```
File "dayoftheyear.py", line 12, in <module>
e = sum(d) + Day
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Please, help me fix it.

Comment: `sum` expect a list, not an int.

Answer (score 0):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function except a iterable (`list`, `tuple`, ...) argument. And `d` is an `int`.
You could sum all days in a loop like

```
...
e = 0
for i in range(len(b)):
  c = b[i]
  d = Months[c]
  e = e + d
e = e + Day
print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` is designed to work on an iterable object such as a list of numbers. e.g. `sum([1, 5, 7])`. It does not quite apply in your situation.

The following might help. As an alternative to finding in the index, you could just stop when the correct month is reached:

```
import sys

user_month = str(sys.argv[1]).title()
user_day = int(sys.argv[2])

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
days_in_month = {"Jan": 31, "Feb": 28, "Mar": 31, "Apr": 30, "May": 31, "Jun": 30, "Jul": 31, "Aug": 31, "Sep": 30, "Oct": 31, "Nov": 30, "Dec": 31}
total = 0

for month in months:
    if user_month == month:
        break

    total += days_in_month[month]

total += user_day
print(total)
```